# Make php files under a certain directory unaccessible using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file in place to redirect all requests that does not hit an existing file or directory to be parsed by my index.php file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # Our app bootstrap file is index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is working fine, But I'd like also to add another rule to prevent any direct access to php files under a certain directory, routing those calls to the same index.php file.

Like so:

> request for example.com/something.php -> ok
>
> request for example.com/themes/(anythinggoeshere)/somefile.php -> not
>   ok, route trough index.php
>
> request for example.com/themes/(anythinggoeshere)/banner.png -> ok

I'm looking for a way to make those "rules" work to everything under the "themes" folder without breaking my current ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a new rule to handle those `.php` requests:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # handle .php requests via index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/themes/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^[^/]+/.+?\.php$ index.php?/$1 [L,NC]

  # Our app bootstrap file is index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Made a few tweaks here and there to fit other needs, but I got the idea.